# Date exportation from Excel to XML

Tags: excel, xml, date

I've been looking for an answer in this forum, but I couldn't find one. I need to export dates from an Excel to xml. When I do so, this happens. In the first picture I show how the Excel looks like:

[image]

In the second picture I show how the xml exportation looks like:

[image]

The problem is that I need the date to be dd/mm/yyyy in the xml exportation, and I don't know how to configure Excel in order for this to happen as I'm very new to xml.

Comment: Change the column to text in excel before exporting.

Comment: Thanks, jdweng! I hadn't seen you answered. Thanks for your time helping me.